# Stopping a UIGestureRecognizer from calling selector

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm adding in a few UIGestureRecognizers with a target and selector.  I'll just talk about one since the other will be the same i'm sure.

I've added a UIPinchGestureRecognizer

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [UIPinchGestureRecognizer new];
[pinch addTarget:self action:@selector(pinchGestureDetected:)];
[self.view setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinch];
```

Now my goal here is to simply call this method once when I receive a pinch gesture.  But obvoiusly it continues to call it as the person pinches.  I'm using it as part of a page navigation and will be updating the view when a pinch in is detected.

So in my -(void)pinchGestureDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer)pinch method I'll be calling another method.  Kinda like ... and this is a little sudo

```
-(void)pinchGestureDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer)pinch
{
if (pinch.scale > 1) layoutViewWithMoreDetail;
else layoutViewWithLessDetail;
}
```

So I don't want it to keep calling this method or the layout method will continue to be called.  I want one layout / pinch gesture.

Is there a way I can stop detecting the pinch once it has determined the scale??  Something along the way of ...

```
-(void)pinchGestureDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer)pinch
{
if (pinch.scale > 1)
{
layoutViewWithMoreDetail;
stop receiving pinch gestures till this.gesture is finished;
}
```

Would I impliment the GestureDelegate??

```
-(void)pinchGestureDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer)pinch
{
if (pinch.scale > 1 && pinching == NO )
{
layoutViewWithMoreDetail;
pinching = YES;
}
```

and then in the delegate for Gesture ended ... pinching = NO;

Thanks for any help

Comment: Oh ya, and I don't see a delegate for the ending of a gesture although there is a -touchesEnded:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UPinchGestureRecognizer` is a continuous gesture - use `if(pinch.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)` to detect whether or not the event is just now starting.

However, this results in a low threshold for triggering the event. An alternate method is to quicky disable and enable a gesture when it has been triggered to your satisfaction, like so:

```
-(void)pinchGestureDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer)pinch
{
    if (pinch.scale > 1)
    {
        //do your stuff here
        pinch.enabled = NO;
        pinch.enabled = YES;
    }
}
```

This is because if you look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it states:

> enabled
>
> A Boolean property that indicates whether the gesture recognizer is enabled.
>   @property(nonatomic, getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled
>
> Discussion
>
> Disables a gesture recognizers so it does not receive touches. The default value is YES. If you change this property to NO while a gesture recognizer is currently recognizing a gesture, the gesture recognizer transitions to a cancelled state.

Comment: hmmm .. but I know it's began.  I need to give it some time to recognize if it's a pinch in or a pinch out and then do the action.  I would set it's state to UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded but I can't and even if I could it would just reset from that to UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan again.

Comment: The state will only be UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan the first time it is called. Afterwards, it will be UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged, or Ended, or any of the others, but not UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan

Comment: Ah ya, the enabled property slipped by me.  Thanks!